# How to drag a Draggable widget OFF of a DragTarget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, draggable

I am looking to be able to do the reverse of dragging a Draggable widget to a DragTarget. I would like to be able to remove the placed Draggable from the DragTarget by dragging it out of the DragTarget and letting go (which would send the Draggable back to it's original location). I feel like this should be a simple feature, however I can't seem to Figure out how to do this.

Essentially I want to have 2 positions:
Position A: Where the Draggable rests
Position B: Where the DragTarget is

I would like to be able to drag the Draggable to the DragTarget and then Drag the draggable that is now at position B away from the DragTarget and drop it anywhere (except back on the DragTarget) to make it go back to position A.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think essentially you want a widget that is a Draggable AND a DragTarget.  I'm trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @Marvin Yes! I think so too, I've put it on the backburner lately so I unfortunately haven't made progress. If you figure it out please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Very late but it can help others who need it.

You can place a `Draggable` inside the `DragTarget`

```
  int objPosition = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget emptyContainer = Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: const Center(
        child: Text('EMPTY'),
      ),
    );
    Widget objWidget = Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.orange,
      child: const Center(
        child: Text('OBJ'),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // DragTarget 1
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: DragTarget<int>(
              onWillAccept: (obj) => obj == 1,
              onAccept: (obj) => setState(() => objPosition = 0),
              builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
                if (objPosition == 1) {
                  return emptyContainer;
                }
                return  Draggable<int>(
                  data: 0, // <-- objValue
                  feedback: objWidget,
                  child: objWidget,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),

          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 220,
            child: DragTarget<int>(
              onWillAccept: (obj) => obj == 0,
              onAccept: (obj) => setState(() => objPosition = 1),
              builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
                if (objPosition == 0) {
                  return emptyContainer;
                }
                return Draggable<int>(
                  data: 1, // <-- objValue
                  feedback: objWidget,
                  child: objWidget,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```